# iCloud Mail isn’t filtering junk mail properly

Tags: macos, ios, icloud, mail.app, email

I constantly get junk email into my main inbox, and it never actually seems to filter junk mail to the junk inbox. Even when I move the junk mail into the proper folder, more junk mail will turn up into my main inbox. Is there a way to fix this? It’s insanely annoying and nothing I do seems to fix the problem. I’m referring to my email address with “@icloud.com” here, not the Apple mail app itself.

Comment: This is a problem that plagues all email providers, not just Apple's @iCloud.com domains.  If there was a definitive way to stop junk email, it would've been implemented by everyone by now.